# How avoid NgRx action'type property override my state type property

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I need to keep the property type into my array of object which make up the State.

```
export interface notification {
    date: string;
    description: string;
    time: string;
    title: string;
    type: {
      icon: string;
      typeId: string;
    };
}

export interface NotificationsState {
  data : notification[];
}

export const initialState: NotificationsState = {
  data: [],
};
```

I process the data this way and send it as the argument of my action this way:

[image]

The issue is the action type is overriding the type property of my state:

[image]

I would like to have this value type:

```
type: {
  icon: "check_circle",
  typeId: "info"
 }
```

but I got this: "[Notifications] updateNotifications"

Which is the type of my action:

```
export const updateNotifications = createAction(
  '[Notifications] updateNotifications',
  props<{ notification: notification }>(),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `NgRx` uses under the hood the keyword `type` for handling `actions`. [Look at the docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/actions#the-action-interface)

Try changing your property name for `Notification` from `type` to something else, like `notificationType`